# OCMOD not replacing line correctly

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I want to replace line using OCMOD

I am using below code to replace the line in file **admin/model/sale/customer.php**

```
<file path="admin/model/sale/customer.php" error="log">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[ $this->load->model('setting/store'); ]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[ 
                if($this->isFront==true) {
                    $this->load->adminmodel('setting/store');
                } else {
                    $this->load->model('setting/store');
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

The search line `$this->load->model('setting/store');` is repeated three times in file.

The problem is when I use above code it replace the line unexpectedly. It adds the code somewhere near function which results into syntax error in modification. Example after replace:

```
.....
.....
    public function addReward($customer_id,  
                if($this->isFront==true) {
                    $this->load->adminmodel('setting/store');
                } else {
                    $this->load->model('setting/store');
                }
            $this->load->model('setting/store');der_id = 0) {
        $customer_info = $this->getCustomer($customer_id);

        if ($customer_info) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', points = '" . (int)$points . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($description) . "', date_added = NOW()");

            $this->load->language('mail/customer');
.....
.....
```

What is the solution to replace it correctly? I don't mind if the solution only replace in **addReward** function. Also, I am fine with before, after, replace and regex.

I guess it might be the problem of OCMOD.

Comment: Since you want to replace the first occurrence of the search you need to provide an `index` as `<search index="1">`

Answer (score 0):

in first place use

```
<search index="0">
```

for first match

```
<search index="1">
```

for second match

```
<search index="2">
```

for third match
...

it seems you get conflict from other modification so you can debuge ocmod in these steps:

- go to Modifications >> Tap: log: then hit the clear button
- click refresh and search on your modification by code and file